# How to use findByIdAndUpdate to change a subarray using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a MEAN stack to do list and need help with the following Mongoose syntax.

I am trying to update the completed field of the todos array to true. With research I was able to update my subdocument using the Mongoose model findOneAndUpdate.

However, I am also trying to learn how to use findByIdAndUpdate. I can't seem to get it to work. Where am I going wrong?

My Mongoose document with nested subdocument todos:

```
{
    //this is my userID
    "_id": ObjectId("5b21cbdeebe2b414906b2b31"),
    "username": "john",
    "todos": [{
        // this is my id
        "_id": ObjectId("5b21cbdeebe2b414906b2b32"),
        "item": "testing",
        "completed": false
    }, {
        // this is my id
        "_id": ObjectId("5b22dd570f15b72e949591f6"),
        "item": "adding new",
        "completed": false
    }]
}
```

My Mongoose function:

```
module.exports.markItemCompleted = function(id, callback) {
  Item.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { completed: true }}, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need  to use [$[] positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator in order to update each element in an array

```
module.exports.markItemCompleted = function(id, callback) {
  Item.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { 'todos.$[].completed': true }}, callback
  );
}
```

Note: You should have **mongodb version 3.6**

Comment: I tried this but it still didnt work for me. However, your information link was extremely helpful. I ended up sticking with findOneAndUpdate just so I could move on with my project. Apparently this is something I will have to revisit later on. I appreciate your response. Thank you!!!